# GPG - import a .key file containing only the private key in gpg

Tags: import, key, private, gnupg, pgp

I am trying to restore my backup but somehow the pubring file does only show 1 key pair.

I did import my old(most important) public key from the key server.

So far, so good.

Now I have a lot of keys inside ~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d/

They are all named "longcombinationOfLettersAndNumbers.key"

**Can I somehow use these private keys to decrypt my backup?**

I tried

```
gpg --import < fileOfAKey.key
```

but I get:

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

Any tips/help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `--import` which expects properly exported key like

```
gpg --export-secret-keys --armor KEY_ID
```

You can directly copy `*.key` files with `pubring.kbx`

```
cp /OLD_HOME/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d/SOME_LONG_ID.key ~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d/
cp /OLD_HOME/.gnupg/pubring.kbx ~/.gnupg/
```

Then you can verify that gpg recognizes key file(s)

```
gpg --list-secret-keys
```